# FloatingActionButton covered by prev layout in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

This is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"  
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:elevation="24dp">


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/dialog_frame"
    android:id="@+id/login_close"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I expect FAB floating on linearlayout, but linearlayout is covering FAB.

My xml code to layout screenshot:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. Something is wrong, I think?

Comment: change linearlayout elevation to `android:elevation="2dp"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LinearLayout` have a higher elevation than the `FloatingActionButton` thats why its hiding behind `LinearLayout`

Just remove **`android:elevation="24dp"`** from your `LinearLayout`

**CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialog_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#0000FF"

            android:orientation="vertical">


        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/login_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/dialog_frame"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: oh, i think this is best answer. but why elevation attr cause FAB covered?

Comment: @JYL your Linear have a higher elevation than the Fab  thats why

Comment: @JYL happy to help you

Comment: Nilesh is correct. Fab default elevation is 5dp so if you set linearlayout elevation more than 5dp then fab will be remain hidden behind linearlayout. +1

Comment: i was think 'elevation' attr just means layout's shadow amount.
it's my mistake.  thanks :)